# How do i select each row as separately and i need to add some styles to each row

Tags: javascript

```js
function tableCreate() {
  var body = document.body;
  var tbl = document.createElement('table');
  tbl.style.border = "1px solid #ccc";
  tbl.style.width = "400px";
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var tr = tbl.insertRow();
    for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
      var td = tr.insertCell();
      td.style.border = "1px solid #ddd";
      if (i == 5 && j == 5) {
        break;
      } else {

        td.style.padding = "10px";
        if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
          td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('S.No'));
        }
        if (i == 0 && j == 1) {
          td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Name'));
        }
        if (i == 0 && j == 2) {
          td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Emp.ID'));
        }
        if (i == 0 && j == 3) {
          td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Gender'));
        }
        if (i == 0 && j == 4) {
          td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Salary'));
        }
      }
    }
  }
  //for(var){}
  tr.style.background = '#006699';
  body.appendChild(tbl);
}

tableCreate();
```

Comment: Can you explain us (or add an image) of what is the kind of result you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add styling at the same time as you add the row:

```
var tr = tbl.insertRow();
tr.style. //whatever you want here
```

Or you could loop through the rows later

```
for (var i = 0, row; row = tbl.rows[i]; i++) {
    row.style. //whatever you want here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what kind of result you want…

…but here is a snippet with a random color for each `tr` element:

```js
// ADDED function to pick random rgb values
function getRandomRGB() {
  var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
  var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
  var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
  return "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
}


function tableCreate() {
  var body = document.body;
  var tbl = document.createElement('table');
  tbl.style.border = "1px solid #ccc";
  tbl.style.width = "400px";
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var tr = tbl.insertRow();
    tr.style.background = getRandomRGB(); // ADDED here
    
    for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
      var td = tr.insertCell();
      td.style.border = "1px solid #ddd";
      if (i == 5 && j == 5) {
        break;
      } else {
        td.style.padding = "10px";
        if (i == 0) { /* OPTIMIZED code here */
          if (j == 0) td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('S.No'));
          if (j == 1) td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Name'));
          if (j == 2) td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Emp.ID'));
          if (j == 3) td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Gender'));
          if (j == 4) td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Salary'));
        }
      }
    }
  }
  // tr.style.background = '#006699'; // REMOVED here, it isn't the good place !
  body.appendChild(tbl);
}

tableCreate();
```

⋅
⋅
⋅

You can also do nice things in CSS, using `nth-of-type()` selector:
(Here, it's fixed color values)

```js
function tableCreate() {
  var body = document.body;
  var tbl = document.createElement('table');
  tbl.style.border = "1px solid #ccc";
  tbl.style.width = "400px";
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var tr = tbl.insertRow();

    for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
      var td = tr.insertCell();
      td.style.border = "1px solid #ddd";
      if (i == 5 && j == 5) {
        break;
      } else {
        td.style.padding = "10px";
        if (i == 0) { /* OPTIMIZED code here */
          if (j == 0) td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('S.No'));
          if (j == 1) td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Name'));
          if (j == 2) td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Emp.ID'));
          if (j == 3) td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Gender'));
          if (j == 4) td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Salary'));
        }
      }
    }
  }
  // tr.style.background = '#006699'; // Here isn't the good place !
  body.appendChild(tbl);
}

tableCreate();
```

```css
tr:nth-of-type(3n+1) td {
  background: #ccc;
}

tr:nth-of-type(3n+2) td {
  background: #ddd;
}

tr:nth-of-type(3n+3) td {
  background: #eee;
}

tr:first-of-type td {
  background: #aaa;
}
```

Note that you may want to change your first `td` elements to `th` elements, as it seems you're using them as headers.

Hope it helps.